# Convert logical to matrix with MatLab

Tags: matlab, matrix

In MatLab environment, how can one convert **Logical** to matrix form?

For example, consider the logical below:

> ```
>  [0 1 0 1]
>  [0 0 1 0]
>  [1 0 1 1]
>  [0 1 0 0]
> ```

Comment: Despite having accepted an answer, it would be great if you could clarify whether you had one logical matrix or 4 row vectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say **Logical** array is called LA, Try

```
double(LA)
```

If LA is an array of arrays, as I imagine from your question, you could use:

```
NA = zeros(size(LA))
for i = 1:size(LA,2)
    NA(i,:) = LA(i)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a compact way of doing the conversation  of logical matrix LA:

```
NA = +LA;
```

And if you are dealing with cell arrays of logical arrays you can use

```
NA = cellfun(@uplus, LA);
```